# input field for browsing folder

Tags: html, input, folderbrowserdialog

input field with type file used for browsing file .How to make it for browsing folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The `input type=file` control is limited to picking one file at a time.

If you want to pick multiple files, there are various ways, Flash based uploaders, Java and ActiveX based components. The Flash based uploaders are the best bet, and there are Open Source ones around. Check out [**SWFUploader**](http://www.swfuploader.org).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use server side or some ActiveX to do this as javascript does not support this