# asp.net MVC browse for folder path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to work out what is the best way in an MVC3 form to have an input on a form where you browse for a folder path, not a file.

If this was for a file I would do something like this, but what is the equivalent for a folder?

```
MODEL
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
VIEW
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the folder?

Comment: my code will iterate over all files in the folder, selecting .JPEG ones and uploading them into a CMS. The code will run in an intranet were the server has access to the unc filepath specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an HTML input for folder (only for individual files).

See [How to take folder as a input in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837759/how-to-take-folder-as-a-input-in-html)
See also [WC3 Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select)